# Trouble programatically posting links to a Facebook Page (PHP SDK)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm having real issues posting links to a Facebook Page via the Facebook SDK for PHP (v5.4). I'm using v2.6 of the Facebook Graph API.

I'm using a user who has admin access to the page.

I've got an access token that never expires, with the following permissions: `user_managed_groups`, `user_photos`, `user_posts`, `email`, `manage_pages`, `publish_pages`, `pages_show_list`, `publish_actions`, `public_profile`.

This is my code:

```
use \Facebook\Facebook;
use \Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
use \Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

$app_id       = '123';
$app_secret   = 'ABC';
$access_token = 'XXX';
$page_id      = '123';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'                => $app_id,
    'app_secret'            => $app_secret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
    'access_token'          => $access_token,
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
    $response = $fb->get('/' . $page_id . '?fields=access_token', $access_token);

    // This returns the same access token as I've already got,
    // so I don't know if that's a problem,
    // or if there's just no point doing this.
    $page_access_token = $response->getAccessToken();

    $response = $fb->post('/' . $page_id . '/feed', [
        'message' => 'Test message with link',
        'link'    => 'http://example.com',
    ], $page_access_token);
} catch (FacebookResponseException $exception) {
    echo '<p>Graph returned an error: ' . $exception->getMessage() . '</p>';
    exit;
} catch (FacebookSDKException $exception) {
    echo '<p>Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $exception->getMessage() . '</p>';
    exit;
}
```

At the moment, I'm getting the following exception:

`Graph returned an error: (#200) Permissions error`

Any help with this would be really appreciated. It feels like I'm so close.

Comment: You failed to go look up what the `getAccessToken` method of the response object actually does.